# Cloudfront is not working when the origin point to a CNAME that host a .Net Core application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

So, I want to use Amazon CloudFront (CF) to serve all images for my website using my server as the fallback (origin). However when I point the CNAME of the CF origin to my .Net Core application it's always return the error status code 404

[image]

So the strange thing is that it's working as expected if I point the CNAME of that CF origin to a normal MVC application

[image]

Here is the configuration from my CF origin

[image]

So both .Net Core and MVC are hosted on IIS with the same server, I just switch the path of source code to test for both cases. I expected the response status code will be 302 when I point the CNAME of CF origin to .net Core application. Does anyone know the reason why?